# object is not clickable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using adorner to draw line on canvas which works but the issue I'm facing is that it is not clickable so I have to keep clicking ten times to select it using mouse.
Is there any property setting that I have missed here?

thanks.
amit

Comment: Have you tried `<Canvas Background="Transparent"`?

Comment: no but I have other objects that are clickable but line.

Comment: The problem with transparent is if 2 lines are very close and side by side and I click line A then line B is selected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the pixels (default hittest) to determine whether or not the user clicked a line, the user has to click the line exactly. When a line is very thin this is very hard.

Another way of handling this is by calculation. When the users clicks [calculate the distance between the mouse location and the lines and select the line that is closest.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment)

You could even make an ordered list of the lines that are within a specified radius and select the next line from this list when the user clicks again.